# Apple M1 docker tensorflow - ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow'

Tags: docker, tensorflow, apple-m1

I am building a Django app which requires tensorflow and postgres.

I am building it using docker and docker-compose.

Here is my Dockerfile:

```
FROM --platform=linux/amd64 python:3.9-slim-bullseye

ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE 1
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

WORKDIR /usr/src/app
RUN python -m pip install --upgrade pip

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends netcat && \
    apt-get install ffmpeg libsm6 libxext6 build-essential libpq-dev -y &&\
    apt-get autoremove -y && \
    apt-get clean && \
    rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

RUN pip install tensorflow-aarch64 -f https://tf.kmtea.eu/whl/stable.html
RUN pip install psycopg2-binary --no-binary psycopg2-binary
COPY requirements.txt .
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

COPY entrypoint.sh /usr/src/entrypoint.sh
ENTRYPOINT ["sh","/usr/src/entrypoint.sh"]
CMD ["python", "manage.py", "runserver", "0.0.0.0:8000"]
```

I do not have Tensorflow nor psycopg2-binary in my requirements.txt

Here is the error I get:

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow'

Comment: Seems like the error comes from `manage.py`, so could you share that? Or does it fail before `COPY entrypoint.sh...`? It is otherwise hard to reproduce...

Comment: Also, why are you installing tensorflow for `aarch64` when the image is explicitly fixed for `x86_64`?

Comment: `manage.py` is just `Import tensorflow`. Now to your second point, where do you find this `x86_64`? The Apple M1 architecture is ARM64-based

Comment: First line: `--platform=linux/amd64` in your Dockerfile fixes for `x86_64`.

Comment: same error if I change to `FROM python:3.9-slim-bullseye`, anyways to answer your question amd64 is the M1 pro CPU architecture

Comment: Not it is not, you mean **arm64**. I removed the platform fixation and it worked for me. (Doing `import tensorflow` in the container). I used your Dockerfile without the `requirements.txt`.

Comment: I am so sorry! The reason I used `--platform=linux/amd64` is because postgres throws `django.db.utils.OperationalError: SCRAM authentication requires libpq version 10 or above`. But yes, removing `--platform=linux/amd64` actually does deal with the tensorflow module import. I will update the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `--platform=linux/amd64`, which pulls the `x86_64` version of the image. Otherwise, subsequently installing `tensorflow-aarch64` would be nonsensical, since your container would not be running natively on the `aarch64` architecture and doing `import tensorflow` in python would, with good reason, fail.

Comment: `Subsequently installing tensorflow-aarch64 will be nonsensical` The M1 uses the AArch64, or do you mean because `--platform=linux/amd64` then it does make sense?

Comment: okay, seems to solve the problem by using "psycopg2==2.9.3" instead. I will change the question to the old form, and reward you the answer.

Comment: I rephrased the answer.